# How to test multiple builds of the same module?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, build, npm, gulp

I want to publish a module to several component manager systems: npmjs, bower, etc... plus I want to create downloadable builds as well, for example one in AMD style for requirejs, one in commonJS style, one for the global namespace in browser, minified for each of them, etc... These are more than 10 builds.

I currently have a single AMD build, and I wrote unit tests for it using karma, jasmine and requirejs in an amd style. What do you suggest, how to generate the other builds and the tests for them?

I mean I cannot decide what should I have as a base of transformations. There is a common part in every output package, and there is a package dependent part either.

AMD - requirejs (I am not sure about using the config options)

```
define(["module", "dependency"], function (module, dependency) {
    var m = {
        config: function (options){
            //...
        },
        //...
        //do something with the dependency
    };

    m.config(module.config()); //load config options set by require.config()
    return m;
});
```

commonJS

```
var dependency = require("dependency");
module.exports = {
    config: function (options){
        //...
    },
    //...
    //do something with the dependency
};
```

global

```
var m = (function (){
    return {
        config: function (options){
            //...
        },
        //...
        //do something with the dependency
    };
})(dependency);
```

I don't know, should I develop the common code and build before every test, or should I develop one of the packages, test it, and write a transformation from that into the other builds?

I intend to use gulp for creating the builds and call unit tests automatically for each of them before automatically publishing them. Ohh and ofc I need an auto version number change as well. Btw. is it necessary to call unit tests after the building procedure, what do you think? I just want to be sure, that not a buggy code is published...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are transformation libraries for gulp:

- https://github.com/phated/gulp-wrap-amd (commonjs to amd)
- https://github.com/gfranko/amdclean (amd to standard js)
- https://github.com/phated/gulp-wrap-umd (commonjs to umd I guess)
- https://github.com/adamayres/gulp-wrap (not sure of its capabilities yet, maybe universal with custom templates, maybe nothing)

So it is easy to transform one package format to the two other formats. This can be done with the tests and the code as well. The commonjs can be tested with node and jasmine-node, the standard js can be tested with karma and jasmine, the amd can be tested with karma, requirejs and jasmine.

It would be a poor choice to create a common descriptor and convert that before every test. I don't want to create another language, like coffeescript, etc... so conversion between packages is okay.

Calling unit tests before publishing is okay. There are no other common package types, so this 3 packages will be enough for every component manager I will use.

I am unsure about the versioning. It is not hard to set it manually, but maybe a system like travis or maven could help more... I'll figure out and edit this answer.